# can't install ADB to samsung galaxy tab

Tags: android, adb, galaxy-tab

I tried these tutorials: http://alldroid.org/default.aspx?g=posts&t=862 and http://www.dkszone.net/setup-install-adb-android-debug-bridge-windows-7 , but both of them end in same way, where windows shows message about 64bit architecture, so I can't install ADB:

[image]

Some day ago, I made to work any device, including galaxy tab, with those tutorials and everything was fine. Why now I can't run tab? SE live with walkman runs fine, it worked even before installed adb

Any ideas what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

install Samsung kies. should help

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Samsung Kies does install the USB driver for you to develop on Samsung devices.  You can use adb shells, deploy apps through Eclipse, etc.  At first glance it looks like the program just lets you browse media on the device, but this also installs the driver for development.

Make sure you update Samsung Kies as soon as you install the program.  That was my problem for about half a day... downloading the program right from Samsung's website, I still had to upgrade as soon as I installed it!!  Also.. I had to be very patient with the installation and upgrade.  I also rebooted a few times.  Kies is very clunky.

I've got Kies working with a Samsung Galaxy Player.  I have Kies v2.3.2.12064_9, and my Galaxy Player is model YP-G70 running Gingerbread.